# Doctrine2 query validation and error handling

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine, dbal

I'd like to use the `DBALException` the perform validation opposed to explicit checking of conditions.

For example, deleting a parent record of which the child record holds a reference with 'delete restrict' will though an integrity constraint violation.  This is current in MYSQL using the Doctrine2 DBAL with the mysql pdo driver.

I want to be able to catch the DBALException (successful in doing so so far) and determine right then and there what happened.

I am not asking for a code solution, but rather options or extensions to doctrine that handle and normalize the errors, a simple example would be:

```
catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {

    if($e->getPrevious()->getCode() == 23000) { // Integrity constraint violation
        /*
         * We know the type of problem; cannot delete parent record, 
         * or cannot create duplicate record.
         * But which one is it? And which child table was complaining?
         */
    }
}
```

This is using the PDOException and the SQLSTATE error code to get a general idea of the problem, however it is not specific enough and although it is ODBC compliant, there is no guarantee will with work with every database.

The reason I need this is that I cannot write validation code for every single possible reference that exists or will in the future exist for every entity in every delete procedure.

CLOSED by self:

Realized this is the wrong way to validate, do not use this concept outside of a testing environment.

Comment: Using exceptions to handle workflow like this is wrong: 1 - you get problems with the ORM, since the EntityManager will be trashable (closed) 2 - You have a rolled-back transaction, which basically means you have to trash all your currently managed objects, since they may be in an inconsistent state

Comment: I just figured this out... +1